# Exclude zeroes in sort-filter function

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following function to display a sorted, filtered and constrained array from a database:

```
=array_constrain(
  sort(
        {
          arrayformula('Sheet1'!BP6:BU717)
        \
          FILTER('Sheet1'!$BV$6:$DQ$717; 'Sheet1'!$BV$1:$DQ$1='Sheet2'!$D$11; 'Sheet1'!$BV$2:$DQ$2='Sheet2'!$D$12)
        };
  10;True);
  1;10)
```

It works as desired, but sometimes, the value of some cells from the column that decides the sorting (10th) is 0. I need the sort function to ignore those rows with zeroes, so the array is constrained to the first row with the minimum value that is not zero.

Comment: So, you should filter on that column being nonzero, along with other filters you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this formula:

```
=array_constrain(
  sort(
        query({
          arrayformula(Sheet1!BP6:BU717)
        ,
          FILTER(Sheet1!$BV$6:$DQ$717, Sheet1!$BV$1:$DQ$1=Sheet2!$D$11, Sheet1!$BV$2:$DQ$2=Sheet2!$D$12)
        },"where Col10 <> 0"),
  10,True),
  1,10)
```

Comment: I have a new issue. It throws a #N/A error when the column doesn't have any zero value. In that case I need it to just return the row with the minimum value... I suppose it's related to the query function, but I have no idea about how to fix it.

Comment: I've tested the formula. It'll give `#N/A` when all the data in column #10 is zero. Could you please, share your data sample, so I 'd see what's wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share the sheet, as it contains private info from my company... However, I think I've fixed it. I just added a zero in a cell in the column of sheet1 (that will be col10 after using the filter) , and now it returns the value correctly. Thanks anyway, I really appreciate your help.